# Accumulating values in an array/list (XSL 2.0)

Tags: arrays, xml, list, xslt

I have a requirement for which i need to accumulate values in an array/list. I am not able to populate the values in the array correctly for the different Packed Items.Please help.

The requirement is that for every container, check for every Packed Item, if the quantity (in the current container ->Packed Item) is equal to the "Total" element in any of the preceding siblings.
if yes; Total= Quantity
else; Total=Total+quantity //total is initially 0

This process has to be repeated for all different packed Items. A packed item is identified uniquely by the ItemId parameter in the input xml.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shipment xmlns="http://www.example.org">
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C1</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C2</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>6</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>6</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C3</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
     <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
     <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>0</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
</Shipment>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shipment xmlns="http://www.example.org">
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C1</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>6</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>6</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C2</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Total>10</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>6</Quantity>
      <Total>10</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>6</Quantity>
      <Total>6</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      <Total>7</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>7</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <ContainerID>C3</ContainerID>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
    <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>8</Total>
    </PackedItem>
  </Container>
   <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>4</Total>
    </PackedItem>
     <PackedItem>
      <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <Total>4</Total>
    </PackedItem>
</Shipment>
```

Applied to sample XML, it means:

We have to compare the quantity in every PackedItem to each of the preceding siblings "Total" value. If the quantity is not equal to any of the precding totals then we will consider it as a parameter to form the total for that particular PackedItem in the Container. PackedItems are identified based on their ItemID.

For example: if you see the first container , the value of total for the first container PackedItem1 (ItemID=A123) would be 8 (sum both quantites simply as there are no preceding siblings). Similarly for the second packed item (ItemID=A111) the value of Total would be 6 (as there are no preceding siblings). So now we should have 2 records in our array A123 -> 8 and A111->6

For the second container, the first packedItem (A123) has the first quantity that is 4. We check if it is equal to preceding siblings sum for the same item(which was 8). Since it is not equal it would be considered to get the total. Moving further in the second conatiner we will not consider 8 (in item A123) as it is equal to previous conatiners sum.The next PackedItem (A123) has value as 6. This is not equal to preceding sibling (A123) sum so would be considered for the total. So now we have 4+6=10, which forms the sum for PackedItem A123 in the second conatiner. On similar lines we would have to process the quantities for PackedItem A111. The quantities 5 and 2 would add up to form the total to 7.

This process would be repeated for all the packed Items in every container, updating the total for the items whose quantity is not equal to the sum of any preceding sibling. PFB the xslt (version 2.0) that I am working on.

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

                xmlns:ex="http://www.example.org"
                xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org"
                xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Container"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:param name="computed.totals"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="curr.total"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="ItemID"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="computed.totals"
                                select="$computed.totals"></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="curr.total" select="$curr.total"></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="ItemID" select="$ItemID"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ex:Container">
        <!-- A trick to initialize to an empty node-set, see http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xsl-editors/2000JulSep/0068.html -->
        <xsl:param name="computed.totals" select="/@empty-node-set"/>
        <ex:Container>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="computed.totals"
                                select="$computed.totals"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ex:Container>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ex:PackedItem">
        <xsl:param name="computed.totals"/>
        <!-- Process the current total, taking into accound the totals of preceding siblings -->
        <xsl:variable name="ItemID" select="./ex:ItemID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="curr.total"
                      select="sum(../ex:PackedItem[./ex:ItemID=$ItemID]/ex:Quantity[(($computed.totals)/MyTotal[@ItemID=$ItemID]/@value != .) or not(($computed.totals)/*)])"></xsl:variable>
        <!-- Process current Container elements -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="computed.totals"
                                select="$computed.totals"></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="curr.total" select="$curr.total"></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="ItemID" select="$ItemID"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!-- Process next container, with the updated list of Total already computed -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ex:Container[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="computed.totals">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$computed.totals"/>
                <MyTotal>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ContainerID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ex:ContainerID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$curr.total"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ItemID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ItemID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </MyTotal>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Total')]">
        <xsl:param name="computed.totals"></xsl:param>
        <!-- store the current total of the Container, will be used only when processing the Total -->
        <xsl:param name="curr.total"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="ItemID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ContainerID" select="../../ns0:ContainerID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="CurrentItemID" select="../ns0:ItemID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Quantity" select="../ns0:Quantity"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($computed.totals)/MyTotal[@ItemID=$CurrentItemID and @value = $Quantity]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$Quantity"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="Total" namespace="http://www.example.org">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$curr.total"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I was not able to follow your explanation. How would I perform this task, if I had to do it manually? -- P.S. All your `Total` values are 0, so there will never be a case where "*the quantity ... is equal to the "Total" element in any of the preceding siblings*", unless that quantity is also 0. In addition, items in different containers are not siblings, so that too is confusing.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. The idea is that initially all the "Total" values would be 0. We have to compare the quantity in every PackedItem to each of the preceding siblings "Total" value. If the quantity is not equal to any of the preceding totals then we will consider it as a parameter to form the total for that particular packedItem.

Comment: For the first container since there is no preceding sibling of packed Item A123 hence we simply add up the quantities and the total becomes 4+4=8 as can be seen in the output xml. Similar logic for A111 makes the total as 4+2=6 which is updated for this PackedItem in the output xml

Comment: For the second container, Packed Item A123 has three quantities- 4,8 and 6. The total would be 4+6=10 (8 was not added as it equal to the total of A123 in the first container). So we update the value of "Total" as 10 in the PackedItems where quantity was 4 and 6. For the PackedItem where quantity was 8 we update the total as 8 (no changes as this is equal to Total (A123) in first container). Similar logic applies to Packed Item A111. Total for A111 is 5+2=7 (6 is not considered as it is equal to the total populated for A111 in the first container).

Comment: So we have to keep on computing the value of total for every PackedItem in a container, store the containerID, total and ItemId in an array. For following containers check every Packed Item, compare the ItemID and Quantity to the values stored in the array.If for a given ItemId the value of Quantity is already stored in the array (as the value of total), dont consider this quantity in forming the "Total" value for the PackedItem in the current conatiner.

Comment: Our array could look like this: 

ContID  ItemID  Total
C1       A123              8
C1       A111              6
C2       A123             10
C2       A111               7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet trying to implement the computation of the total values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.example.org"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.example.org">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="cont-pack" match="Container/PackedItem" use="ItemID"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Shipment">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Container[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Container">
  <xsl:param name="computed" as="element(Container)*" select="()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="this-computed" as="element(Container)">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($computed)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="compute-simple"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="compute">
          <xsl:with-param name="prev" select="$computed[last()]" tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>  

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::Container[1])">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$computed, $this-computed"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Container[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="computed" select="$computed, $this-computed"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackedItem/Total" mode="compute-simple">
  <Total changed="true">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('cont-pack', ../ItemID, ancestor::Container)/Quantity)"/>
  </Total>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackedItem/Total" mode="compute">
  <xsl:param name="prev" as="element(Container)" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="prev-total" select="$prev/PackedItem[ItemID = current()/../ItemID]/Total[@changed = 'true']"/>
  <Total changed="{if ($prev-total = ../Quantity) then 'false' else 'true'}">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('cont-pack', ../ItemID, ancestor::Container)/Quantity[not(. = $prev-total)])"/>
  </Total>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied with Saxon 9.6 HE to your input sample I get the output

```
<Shipment xmlns="http://www.example.org">
   <Container>
      <ContainerID>C1</ContainerID>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
         <Quantity>4</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">8</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
         <Quantity>4</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">8</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
         <Quantity>4</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">6</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
         <Quantity>2</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">6</Total>
      </PackedItem>
   </Container>
   <Container>
      <ContainerID>C2</ContainerID>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
         <Quantity>4</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">10</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
         <Quantity>8</Quantity>
         <Total changed="false">10</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
         <Quantity>6</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">10</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
         <Quantity>6</Quantity>
         <Total changed="false">7</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
         <Quantity>5</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">7</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
         <Quantity>2</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">7</Total>
      </PackedItem>
   </Container>
   <Container>
      <ContainerID>C3</ContainerID>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
         <Quantity>3</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">8</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
         <Quantity>3</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">8</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A123</ItemID>
         <Quantity>2</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">8</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
         <Quantity>2</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">4</Total>
      </PackedItem>
      <PackedItem>
         <ItemID>A111</ItemID>
         <Quantity>2</Quantity>
         <Total changed="true">4</Total>
      </PackedItem>
   </Container>
</Shipment>
```

Please check whether that gives the results for the totals that you are looking for. I realize the attributes `changed="true"/"false"` don't belong into the final result but if the intermediary result is fine in terms of the total then it is not that difficult to implement a last processing step that strips those attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.example.org"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.example.org">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="cont-pack" match="Container/PackedItem" use="ItemID"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Shipment">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Container[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Container">
  <xsl:param name="computed" as="element(Container)*" select="()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="this-computed" as="element(Container)">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($computed)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="compute-simple"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="compute">
          <xsl:with-param name="prev" select="$computed[last()]" tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>  

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::Container[1])">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$computed, $this-computed" mode="strip"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Container[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="computed" select="$computed, $this-computed"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackedItem/Total" mode="compute-simple">
  <Total changed="true">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('cont-pack', ../ItemID, ancestor::Container)/Quantity)"/>
  </Total>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackedItem/Total" mode="compute">
  <xsl:param name="prev" as="element(Container)" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="prev-total" select="$prev/PackedItem[ItemID = current()/../ItemID]/Total[@changed = 'true']"/>
  <Total changed="{if ($prev-total = ../Quantity) then 'false' else 'true'}">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('cont-pack', ../ItemID, ancestor::Container)/Quantity[not(. = $prev-total)])"/>
  </Total>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PackedItem/Total/@changed" mode="strip"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin: Thankyou so much for helping. The code works perfectly on a saxon processor. However the product that I am using (SOA suite 11g) provides very limited support for xsl 2.0 functions. Right now, I am getting error from the processor for using the as=element(Container) in the parameter declarations. Also when we give the # in the template mode (#all, #current) the processor throws error. Is there any alternative to these parts in the xslt. Please advice.

Comment: Also it would be really helpful if you could explain on why we use a # in the name of the template mode. I tried to remove the # and the saxon compiler throws an error saying- a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of the variable. So I am guessing that the # in the mode name helps to have all the packed items as the value of the variable. I tried to google for more information on how this works, but could not get any info on this. Please help.

Comment: For the parameter the `as` is doing type checking (which you could remove), for the variable however it is ensuring that the variable is an element node and not a document fragment node which cannot simply be removed. As for `#all` and `#current` not being supported, in that case you would need to make sure you write several templates for the different modes needed in the code, each time naming the mode e.g. `<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="compute">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="compute"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: The error message you cite does not seem to be related to modes, rather to the `as` declaration. The `#` notation does not name a particular node, rather these names `#all` and `#default` relate to known modes, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes

Comment: Thankyou once again :) I removed the mode #all and #current and modified the templates as you suggested in the example. So this error is out of my way!!

Comment: the solution still fails because the feature of type checking done by "as= element" is not supported in my product. I tried few alternatives to defining the variable structure but nothing really worked!! :( Can someone suggest if there is any workaround for this.

Comment: You can rewrite `<xsl:param name="computed" as="element(Container)*" select="()"/>` as `<xsl:param name="computed" select="()"/>` without changing semantics. The code with `<xsl:variable name="this-computed" as="element(Container)">...</xsl:variable>` needs to be written as `<xsl:variable name="this-computed-doc">...</xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="this-computed" select="$this-computed-doc/*"/>`. Untested but hopefully a hint as to how to rewrite the sample.

Comment: Thankyou, That worked like a charm!! During testing, however we are not able to copy any of the nodes outside container. In my real test case we actually have some nodes inside shipment prior to the container nodes. So the xml looks like <Shipment><Header>....</Header><Data>....<Container>...</Container></Data>.I tried modifying the Shipment template to just have an <xsl:apply-template> and an identity template to copy the nodes as it is except container.Also I modified the template match Container exp to template match Container[1]. But that does not solve the purpose.Any hints, please!

Comment: If the `Container` are inside a `Data` parent and not inside a `Shipment` parent then you need to change `<xsl:template match="Shipment">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Container[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>` to `<xsl:template match="Data">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Container[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>`. For `Shipment` it sounds as if you don't need any particular template as the identity transformation template should take care of it.

Comment: Hi Martin.. Thankyou for the suggestions. The identity template did take care of the Header section. However when I changed the template to match Data `<xsl:template match="Data"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="Container[1]"/> </xsl:copy>`  , it copies only Container nodes inside Data. Data nodes look like this <Data><ID>123</ID><Container>...<Container>. The ID goes missing. Please help.

Comment: And there is one more issue .. the xslt processor does not compile the key function `<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('cont-pack', ../ex:ItemID, ancestor::ex:Container)/ex:Quantity)"/>`. The error is "FuncKey only allows 2 arguments". Please advise and thanks a ton for all the help! :)

Comment: Well if there are other elements inside `Data` you simply want to copy then you need to make sure they are processed, so doing `<xsl:template match="Data"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="* except Container"/><xsl:apply-templates select="Container[1]"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>` might suffice. However, "except" is XSLT/XPath 2.0, so your processor might not support that, in that case use `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Container)]"/>`. As for the key, consider to ask a new question about that, it doesn't fit here into a comment.